# calculate date expression and update table in access

Tags: function, date, ms-access, expression

I have a form based on a table.
I have a purchase_date field and an expiry_date field.
I want expiry_date to add 6 months to purchase_date (in my form) and then insert this value into the table.
I have created this expression: DateAdd("m",6,[purchase_date]) as the control source of expiry_date. This works as expected but this value is not being updated/ saved from the form into the table. I have tried using onClick and afterUpdate functions to run the expression but no joy.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Seems that you should tell us more about the problem. As you have a control source, I suppose you are on a form. Please tell us exactly if the form is based on a view or directly on a table. Furthermore, what exactly do you mean by "run the expression"? At the moment, I somehow suspect that you either don't have the expiry_date column in the underlying data or there is no connection between the form control and that column. Please describe in detail what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried OnSave? Your dateadd syntax seems ok. Watch out for any protected cells/sheets! You can generally use activesheet.unprotect if this is the case.

Also, activesheet.calculate might help you, if correctly placed in your VBA.

Comment: thanks...don't seem to have onSave function? I'm using access not excel - so no sheets/cells.

Comment: Then I would suggest form.recalc - after whichever event you wish to use as a trigger.

Comment: Cool! That worked! I used form.Recalc then expiry_date.Value = DateAdd("m",6,[purchase_date]) and it now saves the value to my table! Cheers!

Comment: Great - I'm glad I was able to be of service 

Comment: The question was probably downvoted because "the problem is saving this value into the table" is not an adequate description of the issue. Questions on SO don't need to be "expert" questions but they do need to be "good" questions (well thought out, clearly stated, and with sufficient detail). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Well, I figured out what was desired, and I am a newbie myself!

Comment: Ok, I have amended my question. The above solution seems to have stopped working and I am getting a communication error. I have added the code to purchase_date afterUpdate using @Zephyris suggestion form.Recalc expiry_date.Value = DateAdd("m",6,[purchase_date]) in VB.